# 7z program prompts and asks for the password if I didn't provide one. How to let it just errors out and exit in this case?

Tags: passwords, 7-zip

I'm using the 7z.exe program to extract some `.rar` files. If the file is a password protected file, and if I didn't provide the password, the 7z program prompts and asks for the password. It looks like this:

```
7-Zip 18.06 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-12-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 10199038 bytes (9960 KiB)

Extracting archive: c:\temp\test\a.rar

Enter password (will not be echoed):
```

Is it possible to modify this behavior so that when I didn't provide a password, it just errors out and exit? Thanks.

Btw, I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Doesn't it do just that if you press enter without typing a password?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes. But I use the command in a batch file. User interaction is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty password to allow 7zip silently fail without prompt. This will normally work with unencrypted archives as well.

```
7za.exe x archive_encrypted.7z -p""
```